# Get Listing data only for the specific page

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list here where i am getting data from backend by the use of service. I am getting a maximum of 20 records from backend but in case if i will be getting 2000 records from backend with one service request, the system can slow down so i am looking for showing only 10 records per page and on each click of next page i want the service to fetch the next 10 records from backend. How can i make this possible? Does this implementation needs to be done at the backend or at the frontend? Sorry if i couldn't ask the question in the best possible way but i am a beginner so please help me.

HTML Code

```
<div class="row clearfix" [@routerTransition]>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card main-content" >
        <div class="header">
            <h2>
                {{l('Schools')}}
            </h2>
            <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" *ngIf="isTableLoading"></i>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class=" waves-effect <waves-block></waves-block>" (click)="refresh();"><i class="material-icons">refresh</i> Refresh</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="body table-responsive" style="padding-bottom: 40px">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{l('Name')}}</th>
                        <th>{{l('Registration Number')}}</th>
                        <th>{{l('Enrollment Type')}}</th>
                        <th>{{l('Entity Type')}}</th>
                        <th>{{l('Location')}}</th>
                        <th>{{l('Actions')}}</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let school of schoollists | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: pageSize, currentPage: pageNumber, totalItems: totalItems }; let i = index">
                        <td>{{school.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{school.registrationNumber}}</td>
                        <td>{{school.educationType}}</td>
                        <td>{{school.administrativeType}}</td>
                        <td>{{school.county}}<span>,</span>{{school.city}}<span>,</span>{{school.district}}</td>

                        <td class="dropdown">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                <li *ngIf="supportAdminCheck"><a class="waves-effect waves-block" (click)="editSchool(school.schoolTenantName)"><i class="material-icons">create</i>Edit</a></li>
                                <li *ngIf="supportAdminCheck"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect waves-block" (click)="delete(school)"><i class="material-icons">delete_sweep</i>Delete</a></li>
                                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-block" (click)="schoolDetail(school.schoolTenantName)"><i class="material-icons">details</i>View</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

           <div class="text-align: center;" *ngIf="totalItems > pageSize">
                <pagination-controls (pageChange)="getDataPage($event)" id="server"></pagination-controls>
            </div>
            <!-- <br> -->
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle waves-effect waves-circle waves-float pull-right" (click)="createRole()">
                <i class="material-icons">add</i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript Code

```
  list(request: PagedRequestDto, pageNumber: number, finishedCallback: Function): void {
    this._schoollistService.getAll()
        .finally( ()=> {
            finishedCallback();
        })
  .subscribe((result: PagedResultDtoOfSchoolListDto)=>{
            this.schoollists = result.items;
            this.showPaging(result, pageNumber);
            this.supportAdminCheck = false;
            if (this.appSession.tenant === undefined && this._utilsService.getCookieValue(AppConsts.authorization.roleName) === 'SuperAdmin') {
                this.supportAdminCheck = true;
            } else {
                this.supportAdminCheck = false;
            }
    });
```

}

Comment: I had a same challenge with much more records (30.000+) and what I did was getting all records back from the backend and then made only client side paging to avoid having a huge and slow DOM. The „best“ solution depends on your use case. If in most cases you need all records on client side (or the user will apply several filters) then this approach could be good. If the users will be fine with the first 10 to 20 records in most cases, I would do a server side paging.

Comment: what can be the best approach for server side paging? Our backend server is in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which api framework do you consume?

Most frameworks supports this common feature and can customize pagination (order criteria, number of items...).

In most cases, pagination **needs to be implemented on backend**, and consumed by client like:

`www.server.com/api/v0.1/my-resource?page=1`

You can implement a **`PaginationService`** using Angular HttpClient like:

```
private currentPage = 1;

getNextPage(): Observable<Resource[]> {
    this.currentPage += 1;
    return this.http.get<Resource[]>(BASE_URL + 'resource' + '?page=' + this.currentPage);
}

getPreviousPage(): Observable<Resource[]> {
    this.currentPage -= 1;
    return this.http.get<Resource[]>(BASE_URL + 'resource' + '?page=' + this.currentPage);
} 

goToPage(page: number): Observable<Resource[]> {
    this.currentPage = page;
    return this.http.get<Resource[]>(BASE_URL + 'resource' + '?page=' + this.currentPage);
}
```

Register your service as **Provider** on your **NgModule** (or component-level if you need it).

Comment: I am using swagger UI as the API framework and as the backend support i have asp.net mvc and for the frontend i am angular boilerplate